# How to deploy create-react-app with typescript to Netlify when page returns 404

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app, netlify

My Netlify hosted app keeps returning a 404 "Page Not Found". I've ran things as simply as I can:

- I've followed the instructions on
  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ and am
  successfully running the react app on localhost.
- I've created an app on netlify and successfully connected to my
  github repository.
- When I click "Trigger Deploy" on Netlify, everything runs
  successfully.
- When I try to open the hosted app I get a 404 "Page Not Found"
  https://simple-cors-react.netlify.app/

Comment: I don't see a 404 on that URL. I can see it load the dummy content, with reactjs logo and text

Comment: Thanks. I just managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by changing my deploy settings. I changed:

Build command: `CI= yarn run build`

Publish directory: `./build`

(I get this error in the deploy log:
`10:30:26 AM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'build' versus './build' in the Netlify UI`

Which begs the question "why didn't you just work before if it was already in the `netlify configuration file`?")